# Simple File-based Record Storage with Fast Text Searching for Compact Framework and Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, compact-framework

I have a single table with lots of records (> 100k) that I need to be able to index and search on several text fields. The easiest searches will have the first part of the string specified (eg, LIKE 'ABC%' in SQL). The tougher searches will need to search for any substring within the text fields (eg, LIKE '%ABC%' in SQL).

I need to run on the Compact Framework. SQL Compact is a memory hog and overkill for my one table. Besides, I'd like to be able to run on Silverlight 4 eventually.

The file and indexes can be generated on the full .NET Framework and I only need read capability on the Compact Framework. My records are not especially large and can be expressed in fix length format.

I'm looking for some existing code or libraries to avoid having to write a file-based BTree implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with [bplusdotnet](http://bplusdotnet.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). It runs on the ADO.NET framework so It may not be what you're looking for but it supports the compact framework and may be lighter.

Take a look, hopefully it can suit your needs.